# bootstrap input is longer than fieldset border

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a new form to input some information using bootstrap but problem is the input is longer than the border of fieldset.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form >
                    <fieldset className="border p-2" >
                        <legend className="w-auto" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Information</legend>
                        <div className="form-group row">
                            <label className="col-md-2 col-form-label label-form">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="col-md-10" id="" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

[image]

My question is how to make the input shorter to that it looks inside the fieldset?
Thank for your help.

Comment: remove `col-md-10` and add `form-control` in `input`

Comment: the input will display in the next line, not same line with the label. I want the label and input on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Bootstrap's [form layouts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text). Use an extra div for `col-md-10`.
And as mentioned in the comments... use `form-control` on the input element.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form >
                <fieldset className="border p-2" >
                    <legend className="w-auto text-left">Information</legend>
                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <label htmlFor="myId" className="col-md-2 col-form-label label-form">Name</label>
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="myId" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Additionally:**

- use `text-left` className instead of style.
- use `htmlFor` to link the label to the input for usability reasons

---

I've added a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/qmj9hsor/) where you can resolve the problem with CSS but hopefully you will realise this becomes very counter intuitive.

**Don't use:**

```
.workaround-md-10 {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .workaround-md-10 {
        max-width: calc(83.333333% - 2rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tim, why there is an extra div with 'col-md-10' instead of input with className 'col-md-10'?

Comment: The column has additional padding inside the grid. If you apply it on the input, that padding is used to indent the text of the field, not a good idea. It's a good practice to keep structure (grid) and components separate. The `label` here is the exception because it works better as a grid item. I'll try to workout a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/qmj9hsor/) to explain it properly.